# Ruby on Rails find parameters array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3.5 (can't upgrade at this point).
I am trying to do a `find` based on existence of several params.
Here is my code:

```
qstr = "customer_name_id = ?"
qparams = [customer_engagement.customer_id]
unless customer_engagement.games_opened_since.nil?
    qstr << " and created_at >= ?"
    qparams << customer_engagement.games_opened_since
end
Issue.find(:all, :conditions => [qstr, qparams]).each_with_index do |issue,index|
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: customer_name_id = ? and created_at >= ?
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you print what are the values of `qparams`, make sure it have 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the array you're passing to `:conditions` if `customer_engagement.games_opened_since` is not nil is:

```
["customer_name_id = ? and created_at >= ?", [customer_engagement.customer_id, customer_engagement.games_opened_since]]
```

You don't want `qparams` to be an array within the array you're passing to `:conditions`. You want your array to end up looking like this:

```
["customer_name_id = ? and created_at >= ?", customer_engagement.customer_id, customer_engagement.games_opened_since]
```

Changing your code to this should do the trick:

```
qconditions = ["customer_name_id = ?", customer_engagement.customer_id]
unless customer_engagement.games_opened_since.nil?
  qconditions[0] << " and created_at >= ?"
  qconditions << customer_engagement.games_opened_since
end
Issue.find(:all, :conditions => qconditions).each_with_index do |issue,index|
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can use an anonymous scope:

```
issues = Issue.scoped({})
issues = issues.condition "customer_name_id = ?", customer_engagement.customer_id
issues = issues.condition "created_at >= ?", customer_engagement.games_opened_since if customer_engagement.games_opened_since
issues.each_with_index do |issue, index|
  # ...
end
```